# valueBinding with dynamic string - Ember.js

Tags: ember.js

I've to ask for a question/problem that I'm having,
in a view like this one:

```
Ember.View.create(
  templateName: "testForm"
  fieldName: "test-0"
)
```

I've a textField into the template where I'm trying to pass a custom valueBinding, like so:

```
{{view Ember.TextField placeholder="Title" valueBinding='view.fieldName'}}
```

why ember doesn't set the correct value binding?
Ember is setting just a 'value''s html attribute that I can see viewing the HTML source code with 'test-0' value, but isn't binded.

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a view with default values they need to be in a hash, notice the brackets

```
Em.View.create({
    templateName: 'testForm',
    fieldName: 'test-0'
});
```

Second valueBinding is using single quotes instead of double quotes.  It should be `valueBinding="view.fieldName"`

Other than those two things it works, see http://jsfiddle.net/mlienau/zUDKZ/ for clarity.

Comment: Yes mate, i apprecciate your answer, thanks :)
but, the problem persist always, as you can see the TextField is not binding the value, but is just adding the 'value's HTML attribute.
that's bad cause is meaning that the value is not binded, but just added as HTML value.
i don't know if this is a ember bug, maybe yes.

Comment: I opened a topic on http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/valuebinding-with-dynamic-string-ember-js/1940 if someone have any idea how to fix it, i would really appreciate it